# Python script unable to access storage server

Tags: python, permissions

I'm creating a simple script to copy files to copy from a local machine to a server loation. I'm getting an error message stating access is denied, I believe this is because the server location requires a login.  It's a work server that requires my domain login to access.

Here's my script:

```
import shutil
import os

### Set the source and destination directories ###

source = r"F:\scripts\Python\DIT\SourceTest"

destination = r"\\192.168.128.13\mocap\ViconDB\AWKG\Capture02\20210423_ShootDay06\Ref\_Basil\testDest"

print("Source = " + source)

print("Destination = " + destination)

### Get a list of file names
fileNames = os.listdir(source)

### Check that the source has files in it ###
numberOfFiles = len(fileNames)

if numberOfFiles == 0:
    print("Error: 0 files found")
    exit()
else:
    print("Copying " + str(numberOfFiles) + " file(s).")


### Loop through the file_names then copy files from source to destination ###
for file in fileNames:

    if (os.path.exists(os.path.join(destination, file))):
        print("File already exists in directory")
    else:
        dest = shutil.copy2(os.path.join(source, file), destination)
        print("New file = " + dest)

print("Copy complete")
```

The result that shows up:

```
Source = F:\scripts\Python\DIT\SourceTest
Destination = \\192.168.128.13\mocap\ViconDB\AWKG\Capture02\20210423_ShootDay06\Ref\_Basil\testDest
Copying 6 file(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\scripts\Python\DIT\AutoCopy.py", line 33, in <module>
    dest = shutil.copy2(os.path.join(source, file), destination)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 435, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\192.168.128.13\\mocap\\ViconDB\\AWKG\\Capture02\\20210423_ShootDay06\\Ref\\_Basil\\testDest'
```

I created a test file just to check and confirm if that is the issue.

```
import os

location = r"\\192.168.128.13\mocap\ViconDB\AWKG\Capture02\20210423_ShootDay06\Ref\_Basil\testDest"

fileNames = print(os.listdir(location))
```

Which results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\scripts\Python\DIT\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    fileNames = print(os.listdir(location))
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '\\\\192.168.128.13\\mocap\\ViconDB\\AWKG\\Capture02\\20210423_ShootDay06\\Ref\\_Basil\\testDest'
```

Is there anyway I can make sure authentication is not an issue when running the script? can I add within my python script a way to authenticate?

Running the script on local directories works, as soon as I use a server location I get permission/access errors

Adding an edit to clarify: on the local machine where I'm running the script, I can access the server location and I have the location mounted, so that it does not require a login. This does not seem to fix it for the script though

Comment: As you can see you do not have permission. One way would be first get permission and then try to connect it. It is not about your code. Contact to the domain administrator to get access or activate a VPN etc.

Comment: Just added an edit to explain, I do have permission to access the server location and the location is mapped to the machine that is running the script with my login saved, so that it does not require a login again. I'm unsure why the script does not have permission given that the mount is correct

Comment: This definitely an administrator issue. You may try run the terminal as administrator from the error. You cannot even list files in the `os.listdir`. Can you try `ls destination` to check if that is really because of Python or not.